# 2 different signatures for main method

Tags: java, arrays, program-entry-point

Can we use those 3 dots to create an array at the place of square brackets, like we used it above??
If not then why we are using this declaration only for main??

```
public static void main(String[] args)

or

public static void main(String... args)
```

Comment: because `[]` is more common than `...` and sometimes a bit easier to explain...but of course both work

Comment: `Can we use those 3 dots to create an array at the place of square brackets`   try by coding..

Comment: You can use them interchangeably.

Comment: @lakshman I try to declare an integer array, and the 3 dot array declaration is not working. As it is working in (String...args).

Comment: see my answer below, Integer[] , or for that matter any Array will work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are not two different signatures - under the hood, it is the same signature; the difference is that the compiler uses three dots to allow invocations with variable argument lists.

Since you never invoke `main` directly (well, you shouldn't be, anyway) the difference shouldn't matter to you. The first form of the signature is the first thing you see in the elementary books on Java, so one should stick to square brackets to gain "instant familiarity" by the readers of your code.

Answer (score 1):

I understand this is already answered, but if this can help you to understand more..

To your specific question -

> Can we use those 3 dots to create an array at the place of square
>   brackets

The straight answer is **yes**, and here is the java docs:
http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html#varargs

```
(String... args)
```

Here the main thread calls the main method passing some arguments. The type of parameter declaration is Array, but when method is called you can pass one or more String objects or an array of String objects, as parameters of that function. There's no speciality for main() in this case.

Also, you could call a myMethod(String.. args) in any of the following ways:

```
myMethod(); // Likely useless, but possible
myMethod("one", "two", "three");
myMethod("one");
myMethod(new String[]{"a", "b", "c"});
```

**Important Note 1:** The parameter(s) passed in this way is always an array - even if there's just one. Make sure you treat it that way in the method body.

**Important Note 2**: The parameter that gets the ... must be the last in the method signature. So, myMethod(int i, String... strings) is okay, but myMethod(String... strings, int i) is not okay.

You also mentioned that You tried with 'Integer[]' and it didnt work,
Here's an example

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer[] a = new Integer[4];
        a[0] = 10;
        a[1] = 20;
        a[2] = 30;
        a[3] = 40;
        myMethod(a);
    }

    public static void myMethod(Integer... args) {
        for (Integer i : args) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are overloading main method here and both are allowed to invoke execution as Paramater type of main method is an `Array` of `String`...

Mentioned in [JLS 12.1.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.1.4)

> The method main must be declared public, static, and void. It must
>   specify a formal parameter ([§8.4.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.1)) whose declared type is array of
>   String. Therefore, either of the following declarations is acceptable:

```
public static void main(String[] args)

public static void main(String... args)
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this way. If java used reflection to find the main method it would do something like this (line 6)

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        if (!(args.length == 1 && args[0].equals("Hello World"))) {
            System.out.println("You did not recurse!");
            Main.class.getDeclaredMethod("main", String[].class).invoke(null, (Object) new String[]{"Hello World"});
        } else {
            System.out.println("You recursed!");
        }
    }
}
```

It would find a function declared with `...` or `[]` then invoke that function.